# How to get the string in a seperate variable after the specified Regex is matched in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string lets say,

```
const message = 'This is a relationship: Salary = 73010 - 58.9 * Potential'
```

What I am trying to achieve here is get everything after `relationship:` and put it in a seperate variable using Regex. After storing the new string in a seperate variable I want the old variable containing the whole string to be replaced with just

```
message = 'This is a relationship'
```

So far, I have managed to do this:

```
const equation = new RegExp(/relationship:.*$/); // this gets everything removed starting from the relationship:
const tooltip = message.split(equation);
const tip = message.replace(equation, '');
```

Apologies for my noob code. I just started understanding Regex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the pattern always everything after `:`? If so this is quite simple, you don't even need an explicit regex:

```js
let message = 'This is a relationship : Salary = 73010 - 58.9 * Potential';

const array = message.split(":");

message = array[0].trim(); // Overwrite the original message (you asked for this)
const tooltip = array[1].trim();

console.log(`message: "${ message }"`);
console.log(`tooltip: "${ tooltip }"`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

This returns:

```
message: "This is a relationship"
tooltip: "Salary = 73010 - 58.9 * Potential"
```